# Where do I go next?

Tags: terrible-tiny-traps

I've been playing [TerribleTinyTraps](http://www.draknek.org/games/tinytraps/) and, while it is fairly straightforward game, I find myself lost as to what to do next.

Here is my current state:
[image]

I've gotten 5 of the 12 objectives, and as far as I can tell, I have two immediate options (which I have free-hand labeled "A" and "B"):

[image]

But both A and B seem to be physically impossible to reach, however. Along my prescribed path to A there is a moving obstacle which seems to always remain too high to cross. While B's only apparent access point seems to be just to high for me to reach.

I marked these points of contention "C" and "D":

[image]

So at this point I'm pretty much at a loss for how to continue.

**How do I get my next objective?**

Answer (score 3):

You can get past both C & D.

C: what you have been trying is not going to work. But perhaps there is a less obvious way to get past?

D: you need to gain a small bit of height, is there a step anywhere?

(Sorry for the vagueness, I made the game so I have a built-in aversion to just telling people solutions)

Comment: Not bad :) [img](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hzAmf.png)